# peventDefault() and return false in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, function, operators

2 questions.

1. Why is `e.preventDefault();` you can't write `return false;` ? (it doesn't work) Although in the case of the purpose of an event via `menu.onclick = func.. return false;` works.
2. Why ternary operator you cannot use the word `return` and it is impossible to ignore the part that starts with ":" ?

Handler assigned to a parent element
markup  div#menu > ul > li > a

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="...">link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
 menu.addEventListener("click", disableLinks, false);

 function disableLinks(e) {
     e.target.nodeName == "A" ? e.preventDefault() : true;
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: 1. Please see the differences between the two methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false); 2. You can `return` with the ternary operator like this: `return condition ? 'thing' : 'other thing'`; and you should be using the construct `condition && action()` if you want to ignore the last part of the ternary.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why is e.preventDefault(); you can't write return false; ? (it doesn't work) Although in the case of the purpose of an event via menu.onclick = func.. return false; works.

That's simply the way it works. Events added inline (in HTML attributes) or assigned directly to the `onclick` property can be canceled by returning false. For events added using `.addEventListener()` you can use `e.returnValue = false` to achieve the same effect, but `.preventDefault()` is the standard way to prevent the default behavior. AFAIK, the option to return false is not defined in the W3C standard.

```js
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
menu.addEventListener("click", disableLinks, false);

function disableLinks(e) {
    e.returnValue = false;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> 2. Why ternary operator you cannot use the word return and it is impossible to ignore the part that starts with ":" ?

A conditional operator consists of three *expressions* separated by `?` and `:`. Expressions cannot contain `return`.

However, since the conditional operator evaluates to a value (that's what it's for), you can `return` the value that it evaluates to:

```
return somethingIsTrue ? 'yay!' : 'no!';
```

It looks like you're trying to use the conditional expression as as a lazy substitute for an `if-else` statement, but it is not a substitute for an `if-else` statement. If you want to use an `if-else` statement, then use one.

I have no idea what *"it is impossible to ignore the part that starts with :"* means.